# Wordpress - Replacing attachment.php with a lightbox

Tags: php, wordpress, lightbox

For each single post page on my WP, I have a large images that, when clicked, link to an attachment.php page where you can click through to view all images in the gallery (by clicking next).

What I need is, when an image is clicked in a post, for a lightbox gallery to pop up where one can click through and view all the images in the gallery.

I do not want a gallery style layout in my posts (thumbnail grid), because I have text and links interspersed throughout each post.

Answer (score 2):

The [Lightbox Wordpress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lightbox-plus/) is another one to try out. I use this one on several of my clients' sites. Just install and follow settings instructs. This is typically by default, but, regardless of the plugin you choose, make sure each image that you upload is linked to the File URL so that the pop up actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I use Lightbox 2 WP plugin to accomplish what you're wanting.

Links: [Plugin page](http://stimuli.ca/lightbox/) & [Plugin page on WP.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lightbox-2/)